# How to search and replace a fragment of text in MS Word document using PHP

Tags: php, replace, ms-word

Main goal:
create documents (with tables) in Microsoft Word using PHP.

Critical problem encountered:
calling:

```
$document->Range->Find->Execute( ... );  // causes ERROR.
```

I get information about: line, File, Source: unknown, Description: unknown;

How do I do it (operations in Microsoft Word using PHP):

- I open a document template from a file (success)
- I insert plain text into the document using

```
    ->Range->InsertAfter(  "whatever text needed to be inserted" ); // (success)
```

- I define a new Range object:

```
    $range = $document->Range( x, y );
```

- and convert the Range into a Table (success)

```
    $Table1 = $range->ConverToTable( wdSeparateByTabs, 1, 2, 30, wdTableFormatNone, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, wdAutoFitWindow, wdWord9ListBehavior );
//  with
    wdSeparateByTabs = 1
    wdTableFormatNone = 0
    wdAutoFitWindow = 2
    wdWord9ListBehavior = 1
```

- Despite the fact that i pass number_of_rows=1 (2nd parameter), the table looks as expected.
- Next step I want, is to make Word find and replace strings:

```
$rng = $Table1->Range;
$find = $rng->Find;
$find->Execute( "text to find", false, false, false, false, false, null, wdFindContinue, false, "text to be replaced with", wdReplaceAll, null, null, null, null );
```

Some system info:

- all on a virtual machine Oracle VM VirtualBox 5.2.0
- Windows XP sp3
- Apache 2.2.6
- PHP 5.2.9
- Microsoft Office Word 2002 (10.2627)

Final thoughts and ideas:

- when I comment out the ->Find->Execute( ... ) section - all is done as expected
- I create a table from a plain text with cells separated by a character (tab in my example) thus I can't create a cell with multiple lines (\x0A) this way because Word uses \x0A as a separator too (tested);
- I need to have cells with multiple lines (separated by \x0A or \x0B)
- the idea was to insert a plain text with html's < br > line separator, convert it to a table, and replace '< br >' with \x0A or \x0B when the table is created
- I'm positive that I can achieve needed goal different way (ways)
- I've done a very similar test using C# in VisualStudioExpress2010, but all  works as expected, I don't get an ERROR as I do using PHP

What do I do wrong that calling

```
->Range->Find->Execute(...);
```

causes an error?

EDIT:
I don't use frameworks, just plan Word, and stock PHP

```
$word = new COM( 'Word.Application' );
$document = $word->Documents->Add( ); //or
$document = $word->Documents->Open( 'template_file.doc' );
```

Comment: you are using phpword I presume

Comment: I did not say it but I don't use any frameworks just plain Word and stock PHP ~~~~ $word = new COM( 'Word.Application' ); $document = $word->Documents->Add( );~~~~

Comment: find out the exact error first. http://php.net/manual/en/com.error-handling.php

Comment: skimming through the question I don't see the actual error code and text? That would certainly help people looking at this to figure out where the problem might be... It's also not clear exactly what is not working as it should.

Comment: @KrzysztofP find contains 15 parameters, but you omit them with ellipses, confident?